# How to work with Proportion of variance explained in PLS Regression?

Tags: regression, pca, latent-variable, partial-least-squares

I have some very basic questions regarding PLS.

I ran PLS using SPSS on small dataset.
n=312,
Dependent variable=1;
Independent Variables=9.

Here is the output of Proportion of Variance Explained.
[image]

As you can see, 8 latent factors were necessary to explain 100% variance in X (Independent Variables). However, only about 7% variance is explained in Y (dependent variable) by all latent factors.

I want to ask,

1. How do you decide if the model is well-fitted? Is it based on X-Variance Explained? or Y-Variance Explained?
2. In case if it is required that, a well-fitting model would explain most of the variation in both the X and Y. What can be done here? Should I use any other technique to Analyse my data?
3. Is there a way to improve Y-Variance explained?

Thank you so much for your kind time.